# Flex Components and main.mxml communication

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, components

I'm building a Flex 4 Application in AIR.

I've made a main.mxml and a login.mxml component. It all works but i can't communicate between my two mxmls (MAIN and COMPONENT)

The login works but then it has to send a event tot the main that i can change the state in the main.

Here is my cropped code.

**login.mxml**

```
//resulthandler if login is succesfull
                loginUserResult.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, loginUserResultHandler);

        public function loginUserResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            if(loginUserResult.lastResult == 1)
            {
                dispatchEvent(new Event('myLoginSuccesfull'));
                trace("dispatchEvent - myLoginSuccesfull ");
            }
            else
            {
                this.loginErrorLBL.text = "Username and/or password aren't valid.";
            }
        }
```

So the login.mxml sends the event succesfully.

**main.mxml**

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            loginInstanceCom.addEventListener('myLoginSuccesfull', onLoginSuccesful);
        }

        protected function onLoginSuccesful(event:Event):void{
            trace("onLoginSuccesful recived");
            currentState = "main";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="State1"/>
    <s:State name="main"/>
</s:states>

<components:login id="loginInstanceCom" x="263" y="10" width="239" height="223" includeIn="State1">
</components:login>
```

So, the instance from the component loginInstanceCom isn't recognized in the windowedapplication initialize where i use the same id.

It gives the following error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Hopefully someone can help me.
Thanx!

Comment: can't you just use a view stack instead of states? States are so ugly in flex in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Although you didn't specify, I am assuming that the login.mxml component is a child of the main.mxml component.

To dispatch an event, do this:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('myLoginSuccesful'));
```

You may want to add metadata to the component to have that event show up in code hinting, but it is not required.

Listen for the event in your main application:

```
loginInstance.addEventListener('myLoginSuccesful',onLoginSuccesful);
```

I would probably add this code in the initialize handler of the main component.

In your handler method, just change the state:

```
protected function onLoginSuccesful(event:Event):void{
 currentState = 'main';
}
```

Comment: hello,
thanks for your fast answer. I'm quite new to Flex and Actionscript but i understand you're answer. The only thing now is that the myLoginInstance is what?

myLoginInstance = the id of the component? (gives a fault)
myLoginInstance = a public var myLoginInstance:login where login is the name of the custom component? because this also gives an error.

If you have the time please answer.

Kind regards,
Gizzy

Comment: myLoginInstance would be the name of hte instance of your MyLogin.mxml component.  When the instance is created in MXML that would would be the id tag.  When an instance is created in ActionScript that would be the variable name.

Comment: my instance is created in MXML like this

`code`<components:login id="loginInstance" /> in the MainApplication. And it still says that i can't refer to a null object... I do not understand what i'm doing wrong. Please help, because it's getting frutrating. Kind regards, Gizzy

Comment: I modified the code in my answer to specify your explicit instance name.  Basically "loginInstance.addEventListener('myLoginSuccesful',onLoginSuccesful);"  IF that doesn't help; you should edit your question to post a more expansive code segment.

Comment: I think i'm beeing misunderstood, my component is only 'declared' in my mxml code like this -> <components:login id="loginInstance" /> and it doesn't recognize the id? I really don't understand...

Comment: I believe I understand.  If the code I provided doesn't work; then something else is wrong.  I may be able to diagnose very quickly if you were to post your full code.  Please edit your original question to do so.  Also include the error your are receiving.  Is it a compiler error?  Or a runtime error?

Comment: I've edit my code, this is my first time on this form so i hope my question is well formed. Greetz Gizzy

Comment: Your code has two end script tags; so that could be an issue causing compiler errors.  Other than that, your code should work as written.  You can move the "windowedapplication1_initializeHandler" method from listening to the initialize event (what I recommended) to the creationComplete event to see if that affects things.

Comment: with the creationComplete event the loginInstance gets recognized! Thanx man! Why do you prefer the initialize event? Greetz

Comment: Read up on the component lifecycle.  Initialize should dispatch after createChildren() does, so your component should already be created and in a state where you can add eventListeners to it.  creationComplete is the last step in the component creation lifecycle. Often people use to force the full lifeccle to re-render by doing something that causes components to be re-measured or updated somehow.  It probably doesn't matter for adding an eventListener; but for some things you want to make the changes as early in the process as possible for opitmization purposes.

Comment: Thanks man, you've helped me a step futher for my college project!

Comment: Well, if this fully answers your questions; be sure to mark it as such.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Swiz framework for dispatching events using metadata tag before the method where you want to dispatch the data.
and then you can use the currentstate statement to fix the state you want to view.

Comment: -1 from me.  The Swiz Framework metadata does not dispatch events; it only adds listeners for those events.  It is still up to you to dispatch said event; and for Swiz to call the handler method you have to dispatch that event using the Swiz Event Dispatcher.

Comment: Listeners are used to perform the events in right manner. You can understand what i mean to say as I have used many times "swiz.dispatchEvent()". I have just tried to make a way out of the said problem above.